# Namespace declaration at child nodes instead of root node

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

I have two XML schemas - first one is the envelope which includes the second XML schema as a child node. I marshall-unmarshall child node by itself (both are annotated with @XMLRootElement) and the root node together with the child node.

When I marshall the root JAXB object which contains the child object, I need to get:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://ns0.com" xmlns:ns1="http://ns1.com">
<ns1:Element1/>
<ns1:Element2/>
..
<Child targetNamespace="http://child.com" xmlns:ns2="http://ns2.com", xmlns:ns3="http://ns3.com">
  <ns2:ChildElement1/>
  <ns3:ChildElement2/>
  ..
</Child>
</ns0:Root>
```

But instead I get something like:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://ns0.com" xmlns:ns1="http://ns1.com" ns4="http://child.com" xmlns:ns2="http://ns2.com", xmlns:ns3="http://ns3.com">
<ns1:Element1/>
<ns1:Element2/>
..
<ns4:Child>
  <ns2:ChildElement1/>
  <ns3:ChildElement2/>
  ..
</ns4:Child>
</ns0:Root>
```

So all the namespace declarations are placed at the top root node, and the target namespace of the child node also gets a prefix. I also created a NamespacePrefixMapper to customize namespace prefixes.

How can I customize my marshalling process/JAXB objects to get the required output? The endpoint is expecting this exact format and not in our control. It probably could be possible if I used DOM directly to inject the child node which I will marshall separately into the root element, but this doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it.

Thanks for your input.

Regards,
Gökhan

Comment: did you get solution for this problem?

Comment: I had to marshall the child element separately and inject it within the parent element as XML afterwards. Seems like there's no standard way of doing this with JAXB.

Comment: Can you please share some snippet for this?  Because I have multiple root elements within large XML which I need to generate?